# I can't access private files in CKEditor

Tags: 7, files

I have this site someone else has worked on and they've asked me to see if I could fix something.
This site has private files available to users after they've filled in a form (they then get a email with a link to the private file). This all works the way it should.

Now what they want is to be able to add a link or image that is private.
When doing this the image doesn't show or the link to the file gives a 403 error.

What is the best way to fix this or make this work.

Search for picture through ckeditor

[image: Find Picture]

picture doesn't show
[image: Picture doesn't show]

Comment: I don't really understand your question, when do you get 403, and is it a drupal private file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding the situation correctly, then the issue is that, by virtue of bring a private file, they would need the right permissions in order to view the file in their browser.

On the sites I work on, we use elFinder, and the permission to allow access is called **Access private files**.
[image]

If you're not using elFinder, then there is probably a similar permission that you'll need to enable.

Hope that helps!